# Draw portion of image in CGBitmapContext

Tags: cocoa, macos, core-graphics

I have created a `CGBitmapContext` of 256 x 256 and I have a `CGImageRef` that I want to draw into this context. My goal is to crop the image (and ultimately create tiles of an image), but if I use `CGContextDrawImage`, Core Graphics scales the image to fit the context.

So the question is, how do I make sure that only a portion of the `CGImageRef` is drawn into the `CGBitmapContext` (no scaling)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CGContextDrawImage` takes a `CGRect` parameter.  It sounds like you are passing the bounds of your context.  Instead, try passing the bounds of the image, offset appropriately to draw the desired part of it.

Comment: For example, to draw a 32x32 chunk of the source image starting at (10, 20), you'd do: `CGContextDrawImage(theContext, CGRectMake(10, 20, 32, 32), theImage);`

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan: no, that would scale the image.  Suppose the source image is 1024x1024, and you want the lower right 256x256 corner to fill the context.  Then I think you'd say `CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake( -768, 0, 1024, 1024 ), theImage)`.

Comment: Erm... yeah. What was I thinking? I use Quartz every day! To crop, you need to first set the clipping area of the context with `CGContextClipToRect()`.

Comment: The question wasn't completely clear, but my interpretation was that bare_nature wants to clip to the bounds of the context, in which case a clipping area wouldn't be needed.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. This was exactly what I did, but I made a beginners mistake by using the -size of the NSImage to determine its width and height and this does not necessarily give you the width and height in pixels. All is working well now. Also, clipping is not necessary in my case.